# SQL - sum entire column without group by and create a new column which is grouped

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, case

I have a situation where I want to sum the entire column, without grouping, but I also want the final output to be grouped for a particular country. For example, my input table looks something like this:
[image]

I want the output to sum columns at overall level and then create a new column with the sum individually for each country, so for UK, entire Headcount_UK, gets summed
[image]

I have tried using case and sum statement, but it is summing for that particular row and not the entire column.

```
 Select country,
                        SUM(CASE When country='UK' THEN (Headcount_UK)
                                     when country='ASIA' THEN (Headcount_Asia)
                        when country='USA' THEN (Headcount_USA)
                        when country='AFRICA' THEN (Headcount_Africa)
                     else 0 END) AS TOTAL
    from students
    group by country
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different methods below. The first uses a CTE with several UNIONed queries to get your totals; however, this calls the table many times. You'll probably want to use the 2nd method, which simply uses `conditional aggregation`. But your DBMS may not support this because it's also incorporating a `windows function` (sum over).

**Query #1**

```
with country_totals as (
  select 'UK' as country, sum(headcount_uk) as total from students union
  select 'ASIA', sum(headcount_asia) from students union
  select 'USA', sum(headcount_usa) from students union
  select 'AFRICA', sum(headcount_africa) from students
  )
select
 s.*, 
 ct.total
from students s
join country_totals ct
  on s.country = ct.country;
```

| country | headcount_uk | headcount_asia | headcount_usa | headcount_africa | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 90 | 6 | 1 | 11 | 106 |
| ASIA | 5 | 280 | 5 | 9 | 295 |
| USA | 10 | 7 | 70 | 4 | 79 |
| AFRICA | 1 | 2 | 3 | 25 | 49 |

---

**Query #2**

```
select *, 
 case 
  when country = 'UK' then sum(headcount_uk) over ()
  when country = 'ASIA' then sum(headcount_asia) over ()
  when country = 'USA' then sum(headcount_usa) over ()
  when country = 'AFRICA' then sum(headcount_africa) over ()
 end totals
from students;
```

| country | headcount_uk | headcount_asia | headcount_usa | headcount_africa | totals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 90 | 6 | 1 | 11 | 106 |
| ASIA | 5 | 280 | 5 | 9 | 295 |
| USA | 10 | 7 | 70 | 4 | 79 |
| AFRICA | 1 | 2 | 3 | 25 | 49 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nag4Gpzo1b4YDpwz6Nhee3/5)

Answer (score 1):

See example

```
with totals as(
  select 
     sum(headcount_uk)sum_uk
    ,sum(headcount_asia)sum_asia
    ,sum(headcount_usa)sum_usa
    ,sum(headcount_africa)sum_africa
  from students
)
select s.* 
  ,case when country='UK' then sum_uk
        when country='ASIA' then sum_asia
        when country='USA' then sum_usa
        when country='AFRICA' then sum_africa
    end totals
from students s, totals t
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works as well. it is easy to comprehend as well